# Comparing std::minmax against a pair

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14, minmax

The standard algorithms `min` and `max` can be compared against a single value. However, the `minmax` algorithm return value cannot be compared against a pair of values:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template<class T1, class T2>
constexpr auto make_cref_pair(T1&& t1, T2&& t2)
{
    return std::pair<T1 const&, T2 const&>(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2));
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::min(2, 1) == 1); // OK
    static_assert(std::max(2, 1) == 2); // OK
    //static_assert(std::minmax(2, 1) == std::make_pair(1, 2)); // ERROR, const int& vs int pair comparison
    static_assert(std::minmax(2, 1) == std::pair<const int&, const int&>(1, 2)); // OK
    static_assert(std::minmax(2, 1) == make_cref_pair(1, 2)); // OK
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1143ff935c4b0ab)

The reason is that `make_pair(2, 1)` returns a `pair<int, int>` and `minmax(1, 2)` returns a `pair<const int&, const int&>`. There are no referenceness-mixing `operator==` overloads for `pair`.

The fix is then to explicitly write `std::pair<const int&, const int&>(int, int)` or to wrap this in a home-made `make_cref_pair` function.

**Questions**: is there a cleaner way to compare the `minmax` return value against a `pair` of values? And did I correctly handle the references in my `make_cref_pair`?

Comment: I fear that `make_cref_pair` may not be legal (life time extension doesn't apply to sub-objects, AFAIK)

Comment: @sehe yikes. Does the same apply to the naked `pair<int const&, int const&>(1,2)`?

Comment: It would be the same. I'm not really sure about this, but it does seem like playing on the edge there

Comment: Maybe another way would be to provide the appropriate `operator==` overload by oneself. It's probably safer than `cref_pair` when it comes to object life, but on the other side it's introducing an "unexpected" overload.

Comment: @sehe It seems no more dangerous than, say, `forward_as_tuple`.

Comment: @T.C. that would forward temps as rvalues, making them values, not refs, in the tuple?

Comment: @sehe it returns a tuple of references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::minmax` has an `initializer_list` overload. This returns a `non-const` non-reference pair:

```
static_assert(std::minmax({2, 1}) == std::make_pair(1, 2));
```

Unfortunately this may be less performant, since the complexities respectively are "exactly one comparison" and "at most `(3/2) * t.size()` applications of the corresponding predicate".

Comment: well, I will only use the comparison at compile-time (it's for initializing a variable template, hence the C++14 tag, I need the `constexpr`). Thanks, this is a nice answer!

Comment: do you perhaps also know the answer to the lifetime issues using a `pair<int const&, int const&>`?

Comment: @TemplateRex The issue with dangling references is only a problem if you try to access `first` or `second` afterwards. AFAIK this is a problem with `minmax` as well. A plausible workaround is to use `reference_wrapper`.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is take advantage of the `std::minmax` overload that takes a `std::initializer_list<T>` and returns a `std::pair<T,T>`.  Using that you could have

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 10, b = 20;
    static_assert(std::minmax({2, 1}) == std::make_pair(1, 2));
    static_assert(std::minmax({a, b}) == std::make_pair(a, b));
}
```

Which [will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4630df7a71f182f) and allows you to get rid of `make_cref_pair`.  It does call `std::minmax_element` so I am not sure if this decreases the efficiency or not.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to explicitly convert the left-hand side to `std::pair<int,int>`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr std::pair<T1,T2> myminmax(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
    return std::minmax(t1,t2);
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(myminmax(2, 1) == std::make_pair(1, 2));
}
```

Comment: the initializer-list braces are a more convenient way to achieve this

Comment: Whichever variant works best for you. That’s up to you :)